# Adding Text and Value to Array from CreateElement

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5, createelement

Adding createElements - text and Value without the necessary forLoop to the Array.

Tried map, forEach, but memory wise...it is still lagging with numerous entries.

Please help.

```
templateList example:  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

var templateList = new Array();
var selection = document.getElementsByName("name")[0];

for(var i = 0; i < templateList.length; i++) {
var open = document.createElement("Option");
open.text = templateList[i];
open.value = templateList[i];
selection.add(open);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does `templateList` already contain values? Given your `templateList` array, the code may be able to be shortened to `const selection = document.querySelector(".name"); templateList.forEach((value) => selection.add(new Option(value, value)));`. See [`Option`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).

Comment: Yes they are strings. The problem is the for loop has to iterate over and over again. Want to try to find a way to not have to do that..... it is iterating for too many variables in the templateList array.

Comment: Why does it have to iterate over the values (not variables) over and over again?

Comment: i guess putting the selection.add out of the loop and add a nodelist after the loop instead could increase drawing performance

Comment: How it be displaying.... it is for a drop-down box.

Comment: Never heard of a nodeList before!! Will look it up.

Comment: you can also try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Answer (score 2):

you might get a little better performance using a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to build your options and render them all at once into the dom. I´d say there is no non-iterative way

> Because all of the nodes are inserted into the document at once, only one reflow and render is triggered instead of potentially one for each node inserted if they were inserted separately.

```js
var templateList =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var selection = document.getElementsByName("name")[0];
var opts = new DocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < templateList.length; i++) {
  var open = document.createElement("Option");
  open.text = templateList[i];
  open.value = templateList[i];
  opts.appendChild(open);
}
selection.appendChild(opts);
```

```html
<select name="name">


</select>
```

I tested with js-bench and got only minimal advantage (+- 5%) though theoretically it should be less "lagging"

Answer (score 2):

You can create all option string and then add it to `innerHTML` of `selection`. This will be very efficient compared to your solution.

```js
const templateList =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
      selection = document.getElementsByName("name")[0],
      options = templateList.map(v => ` <option value="${v}">${v}</option>`).join('');
selection.innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<select name="name"></select>
```